# AttachedProperty in XAML firing before I can authenticate & determine role

Tags: silverlight, attached-properties

Using VS2008, Silverlight 4.

I have created an AttachedProperty, "RequiresRole", that I'm setting in my XAML. If a user isn't in the role defined by that property, the visibility of said control is set to collapsed.

The problem I'm currently having is that the 'UserHasRole' check (within my Authorization class, as part of the RequiredRole_Callback function) is firing when I load the application, but before I have a chance to login, authenticate, and set the Role for the user. So the property is working, because the menu item is not visible, but it's not currently alerting my UI, after authentication, that the role has changed. I know where to implement it, just not how. INotifyPropertyChanged? Not sure how that'd fit.

I have a few properties in my App.xaml.cs, "IsAuthenticated", which is set to true when a user logs in (using a service to call a SPROC), and "Role", which is the return value of a successful call to Logon SPROC.

Relevant Authorization.cs code:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty RequiredRoleProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "RequiredRole", 
        typeof(string), 
        typeof(Authorization), 
        new PropertyMetadata(RequiredRole_Callback));

    // This callback will be invoked when some control will receive a value for your 'RequiredRole' property
    private static void RequiredRole_Callback(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var uiElement = (UIElement)source;
        RecalculateControlVisibility(uiElement);

        // also this class should subscribe somehow to role changes and update all control's visibility after role being changed
    }

    private static void RecalculateControlVisibility(UIElement control)
    {
        //Authorization.UserHasRole() - is your code to check roles
        if (Authorization.UserHasRole(GetRequiredRole(control)))
            control.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        else
            control.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    private static Boolean UserHasRole(string role)
    {
        string Role = App.Role;
        if (Role.ToLower() == role.ToLower())
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Relevant MainPage.xaml code:

```
xmlns:s="clr-namespace:TSMVVM.Authorization"

<HyperlinkButton x:Name="lnkLogin" 
HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
Tag="Login"
Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
s:Authorization.RequiredRole="Azdmin"
CommandParameter="{Binding Tag, ElementName=lnkLogin}"
Content="Login" />
```

Relevant Mainpage.xaml.cs code:

```
void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!App.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            ContentFrame.Navigate(new Uri("Login", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
```

**Updated Code**
(Note, changed RequiredRole to RequiresRole)
Authorization.cs

```
public class Authorization
{
    #region Attached DP registration

    public static string GetRequiresRole(UIElement obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(RequiresRoleProperty);
    }
    public static void SetRequiresRole(UIElement obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(RequiresRoleProperty, value);
    }

    #endregion

    /// Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for requiresRole.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RequiresRoleProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "RequiresRole", 
        typeof(string), 
        typeof(Authorization), 
        new PropertyMetadata(RequiresRole_Callback));
    // This callback will be invoked when some control will receive a value for your 'RequiredRole' property
    private static void RequiresRole_Callback(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var uiElement = (UIElement)source;

        if (App.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            RecalculateControlVisibility(uiElement);
        }
        else
        {
            EventHandler eh = null;
            eh = delegate
            {
                RecalculateControlVisibility(uiElement);
                ((App)Application.Current).Authenticated -= eh;
            };
            ((App)Application.Current).Authenticated += eh;
        }
    }


    private static void RecalculateControlVisibility(UIElement control)
    {
        //Authorization.UserHasRole() - is your code to check roles
        if (Authorization.UserHasRole(GetRequiresRole(control)))
            control.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        else
            control.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    private static Boolean UserHasRole(string role)
    {
            if (App.Role != null)
            {
                string Role = App.Role[0].ToString();
                if (Role.ToLower() == role.ToLower())
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

App.xaml.cs

```
private static string _role;
public event EventHandler Authenticated = delegate { };

public static string Role
{
    get
    {
        return _role;
    }
    set
    {
        _role = value;
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<HyperlinkButton x:Name="lnkSiteParameterDefinitions" 
Style="{StaticResource LinkStyle}" 
Tag="SiteParameterDefinitions" 
s:Authorization.RequiresRole="Admin"
Content="Site Parameter Definitions" 
Command="{Binding NavigateCommand}"
CommandParameter="{Binding Tag, ElementName=lnkSiteParameterDefinitions}"/>
```

And finally, login.xaml.cs

```
private void LogonService_LogonCompleted(object sender, TSMVVMLogonSVC.LogonCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        ObservableCollection<string> Result = e.Result;
        switch (Result[0])
        {
            case "Logon Failed":
                break;

            case "Logon Successful":
                PageConductor = new Services.PageConductor();
                App.CurrentUser = Result[2];
                App.Role = Result[1].ToString();
                App.IsAuthenticated = true;
                Messenger.Default.Send(new TSMVVM.Messages.FrameMessage() { RootFrame = (Frame)this.Parent});
                PageConductor.GoToView("Home", "main");
                break;

            case "Change Password":
                break;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `INotifyPropertyChanged` is really what you need in this case.  You just need a one shot event when the application has authenticated.

Add an simple event to your App class:-

```
 public event EventHandler Authenticated = delegate { };
```

Now modify your call back:-

```
private static void RequiredRole_Callback(DependencyObject source, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
     var uiElement = (UIElement)source;

     if (App.IsAuthenticated)
     {
         RecalculateControlVisibility(uiElement);
     }
     else
     {
          EventHandler eh = null;
          eh = delegate
          {
               RecalculateControlVisibility(uiElement);
               ((App)Application.Current).Authenticated -= eh;
          };
          ((App)Application.Current).Authenticated += eh;
     }
}
```

Note the removal of the event handler after it has fired is very important, without it you may well have a memory leak.

Comment: This looks like it's on the right track, so I'm pretty stoked. When I type App.Authenticated -= eh; I get an error "An Object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TSMVVM.App.Authenticated'. To fix that, I went with "App app = new App()" inside the else statement, then changed my App.Authenticated -= eh; I also changed the eh.Authenticated += eh; to app.Authenticated += eh;  However, after doing all this, the RecalculateControlVisibility function is never called, and my Menu item (with RequiredRole="Admin") now displays...

Comment: As a side note on this, I need the RecalculateControlVisibility to run when the app loads, so the proper fields are hidden on load, when authentication is required.

Comment: @Scott: You can't just go and create a new instance of App.  Thats my bad though, I'll tweak my answer to correct code.

Comment: Yeah I felt something was wrong about that (hard to persist app wide settings if I'm instantiating a new App), but I've recently come over from the LAMP world, so there's still much I don't know :) TFS crashed at my client site, so everything under the sun is failing & I can't test currently, but I appreciate the help, I'm sure this will work.

Comment: Sorry man, this still isn't working. When I load the app, the menu item I have "RequiresRole = Admin" is still there. If I add a RecalculateControlVisibility(uiElement); manually to the else, it fires and removes visibility. However, after authenticating, it doesn't re-fire once I authenticate. Is it supposed to intuitively do this, or do I need to call something from my Authentication callback in my logon.xaml.cs, or??

Comment: I'm really struggling with solving this on my own. Your methodology for declaring the delegate in my callback function is not something I've been able to find on msdn or the interwebs, so I don't have a lot of context to figure this out. I feel like somewhere in my app.xaml.cs I should be linking my IsAuthenticated property to raise the Authenticated event, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do that :(

Comment: Wow, just like that, got it. Changed my Authenticated EventHandler from 'public event' to 'public static' (I couldn't reference it directly in my IsAuthenticated set)... in my IsAuthenticated set method, I fire Authenticated(new Object(), new EventArgs()); I then changed the type casting (I think thats the term) in Authorization from ((App)Application.Current) to just straight App.Authenticated -= and += eh... and it works! Last question...  Is that the 'proper way'? THANK YOU!

Comment: @Scott: I'm not sure if its the "proper way".  You get away with it because you never had more than one instance of App so whether you use a static event or a instance event probably doesn't make any difference.  As yet its unclear to me why using an instance event didn't work for you.

Comment: I guess I was just concerned about using static everything everywhere. I read somewhere (remember, .NET noob) that static is okay to use, just not willy nilly everywhere (IIRC, it has something to do with static members loading automatically as opposed to on demand). Thanks Anthony, the previous project, guys at my clients office were spending 35-40 hours in code behind setting visibility/disabled/etc based on user role. They're quite happy with the beginnings of this solution :)